# Ejecutar Sql dinamico postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Amigos tengo una duda,
En una funcion recibo algunos parametros para usarlos como filtros, algo asi

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reporte_ventas_grupo(
pgrupo_id varchar,
pfinicio date,
pffin date,
OUT pproducto character varying,
OUT ptotal numeric,
OUT pcantidad integer)
    RETURNS SETOF record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000
    .......
```

en el campo grupo id, viene los codigos seleccionados por el usuario de los grupos que desea ver en el reporte mas o menos viene un varchar de esta forma '1,4,6,8,12'

entonces quiero generar un select como este

> select p.id,p.nombre,d.cantidad,d.precio from ventas v inner join
> ventasd d on v.id=d.venta_id inner join productos p on
> d.producto_id=p.id inner join grupos l on p.grupo_id=l.id where
> v.fecha>=pfinicio and v.fecha<=pffin and v.esactivo=1 and case when
> pgrupo_id='' then true else p.grupo_id in (pgrupo_id) end order by
> p.nombre desc

Claro el select es un poco mas complicado, la funcion completa esta asi

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reporte_ventas_grupo(
pgrupo_id varchar,
pfinicio date,
pffin date,
OUT pproducto character varying,
OUT ptotal numeric,
OUT pcantidad integer)
    RETURNS SETOF record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
rventas record;
vtotal numeric;
vcliente_id bigint;
vvendedor_id bigint;
BEGIN

for rventas in
select p.id,p.nombre,d.cantidad,d.precio
from ventas v
inner join ventasd d on v.id=d.venta_id
inner join productos p on d.producto_id=p.id
inner join grupos l on p.grupo_id=l.id
where v.fecha>=pfinicio and v.fecha<=pffin
and v.esactivo=1
and case when pgrupo_id='' then true else p.grupo_id in (pgrupo_id) end
order by p.nombre desc
loop
pproducto:=rventas.nombre;
ptotal:=round(rventas.precio,2);
pcantidad:=rventas.cantidad;
return next;
end loop;
return;
END;
$BODY$;
```

pero al ejecutar la funcion me da este error

ERROR:  el operador no existe: integer = character varying LINE 8: ... case when pgrupo_id='' then true else p.grupo_id in (pgrupo...

a la funcion la llamo asi

select * from reporte_ventas_test('11,4,6,8,12','2021-01-01','2023-01-01')

Como podria ejecutar el select con el parametro de grupo con varios codigos?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la columna `grupo_id` es de tipo integer y el parámetro `pgrupo_id` es de tipo character varying, no los puedes comparar directamente. Además el operador `IN` espera del lado derecho una lista entre paréntesis de expresiones escalares, no una cadena.

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir el parámetro `pgrupo_id` en un arreglo de tipo integer usando la función `string_to_array` y luego casteando el arreglo a integer. Luego utilizar el operador `ANY` para chequear en cada registro si el valor de la columna `grupo_id` se encuentra presente en dicho arreglo:

```
grupo_id = ANY (string_to_array(pgrupo_id, ',')::integer[])
```